# Dropwizard-Hibernate Lazy fetch is not lazy

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, dropwizard

I am using Dropwizard-1.1.2 with hibernate-5.2.8. I implemented one-to-many relationship like this:

**Parent Table:**

```
@TypeDefs( {@TypeDef( name= "StringJsonObject", typeClass = StringJsonUserType.class)})
@Table(name="parent_table")
@Entity
public class ParentTable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = "UUID",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    @Column(name = "parent_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = NotificationModel.class, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<NotificationModel> notifications = new ArrayList<>();

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public List<NotificationModel> getNotifications() {
        return notifications;
    }

    public void setNotifications(List<NotificationModel> notifications) {
        this.notifications = notifications;
    }

}
```

**Notification Table**

```
@Table(name="notifications")
@Entity
public class ReminderNotificationModel {
@Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "notification_id")
    @Type(type="pg-uuid")
    private UUID notificationId;

    private String message;

    @Column(name = "notification_status")
    private String notificationStatus;

    @Column(name = "scheduled_at")
    private DateTime scheduledAt;

   // getters and constructors
}
```

Now in my DAO no matter if I try native-query, criteria query or get by id on parent table, it always gives me all the notifications as well. Should the notifications be fetched lazily?

**DAO**

```
public class ReminderDao extends AbstractDAO<ReminderModel> {


    @Inject
    public ReminderDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        super(sessionFactory);
    }

    public ReminderModel getById(UUID id) {
        ReminderModel m = get(id);  // m has notifications as well
        return m;
    }
}
```

I was reading hibernate's [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html) which says Lazy is a hint for basic types. However collection is not a basic type. So lazy should have been honored. What am I missing?

> LAZY is merely a hint that the value be fetched when the attribute is
>   accessed. Hibernate ignores this setting for basic types unless you
>   are using bytecode enhancement

Comment: How did you verify that the m has notifications in DAO ?

Comment: I checked in debugger in IntelliJ that notifications array is not empty. Separately I printed the contents of notification array by serializing them using Jackson. Separately still, I print length of notifications array hoping that it would come out as 0 but it did not!

Comment: "Loading the notifications of a parent lazily" is not the same thing as "not loading notifications of a parent and pretend the parent has no notification at all". Loading lazily means that the notifications are loaded only when the code reads them from the list, for example when printing them with the debugger, or when serializing them to JSON, or when getting the size of the list.

Comment: @JBNizet I see. How can I differentiate this from eager fetch then? Is it possible to check whether lazy fetch is indeed setup correctly?

Comment: Well, you've added `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`, and this is the default value anyway. So yes, it's setup correctly. If you really want to test that, then load a parent, end the transaction and close the entity manager, and check that getting the size of the list throws an exception. Or load a parent, then detach it, then check that getting the size of the list throws an exception. Or load the parent, and checkin that `Hibernate.isInitialized(parent.getNotifications())` is false.

Comment: @JBNizet Perfect! thanks. I just did currentSession.close() and fetch the size and DW threw exception. Thanks for your help. If you like you can post this as an answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Loading the notifications of a parent lazily" is not the same thing as "not loading notifications of a parent and pretend the parent has no notification at all".

Loading lazily means that the notifications are loaded only when the code reads them from the list, for example when printing them with the debugger, or when serializing them to JSON, or when getting the size of the list.

If you really want to test that lazy loading works correctly, then load a parent, end the transaction and close the entity manager, and check that getting the size of the list throws an exception. Or load a parent, then detach it, then check that getting the size of the list throws an exception. Or load the parent, and check that `Hibernate.isInitialized(parent.getNotifications())` is false.